# Modelling "If-Then" with equality constraints in an Integer Linear Program

Tags: integer-programming

Can anyone suggest how to model the following as part of an Integer Linear Program?

$x$ is binary and y is integer such that $0 \leq y \leq U$ where $U$ is a known upper bound.

$y$ is chosen elsewhere in the ILP but in addition:

if $y = 0$, then $x = 0$.

if $y \gt 0$, then $x = 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The following inequalities do the job: $$x\le y\le U x.$$

Comment: Many thanks Rob - and so simple too!